# How do I make a message appear and then disappear after a while?

Tags: javascript, function, performance, callback, javascript-objects

I'm having a problem with an issue with a feature on a website. Basically, I want a message to appear two seconds after clicking and disappear two seconds later on the screen.

```js
function messagePT () {
    let messagePortuguese = "<p id='invisivel' class='site-content'>O site é recente e continua em construção. As nossas desculpas por quaisquer problemas encontrados.</p>";
    document.getElementById("flag-pt").innerHTML = messagePortuguese;
    setTimeout(() => {
        let elem = document.querySelector('#invisivel');
                        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }, 2000);
}
function messageEN () {
    let messageEnglish = "<p id='invisivel' class='site-content'>The site is still quite new and remains under construction. Our apologies for any problems encountered.</p>";
    document.getElementById("flag-pt").innerHTML = messageEnglish;
    setTimeout(() => {
        let elem = document.querySelector('#invisivel');
                        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<ul class="intro-lang-menu" id="success-btn">
        <li><a href="/intro" class="intro-lang-pt" onclick="messagePT();"><img class="anim-quick anim-scale-30" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/ico-flag-pt.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="en/intro" class="intro-lang-en" onclick="messageEN();"><img class="anim-quick anim-scale-30" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/ico-flag-en.png"></a></li>
    </ul>


<div id="flag-pt" class="site-content">
</div>
```

Currently the code looks like this, anyone know how to solve this problem?

I tried to put a setTimeOut function inside another one, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see is that when you click on the image you're doing a page redirect because of `href="/intro"` or `href="en/intro"`. To prevent the navigation, you can use the event object to call `event.preventDefault()`, however I assume you want to still navigate to the click, so we may need more details as to what you're trying to do.

Here's an example of `event.preventDefault()`:

```js
function messagePT (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let messagePortuguese = "<p id='invisivel' class='site-content'>O site é recente e continua em construção. As nossas desculpas por quaisquer problemas encontrados.</p>";
    document.getElementById("flag-pt").innerHTML = messagePortuguese;
    setTimeout(() => {
        let elem = document.querySelector('#invisivel');
                        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }, 2000);
}
function messageEN (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let messageEnglish = "<p id='invisivel' class='site-content'>The site is still quite new and remains under construction. Our apologies for any problems encountered.</p>";
    document.getElementById("flag-pt").innerHTML = messageEnglish;
    setTimeout(() => {
        let elem = document.querySelector('#invisivel');
                        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<ul class="intro-lang-menu" id="success-btn">
        <li><a href="/intro" class="intro-lang-pt" onclick="messagePT(event);"><img class="anim-quick anim-scale-30" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/ico-flag-pt.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="en/intro" class="intro-lang-en" onclick="messageEN(event);"><img class="anim-quick anim-scale-30" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/ico-flag-en.png"></a></li>
    </ul>


<div id="flag-pt" class="site-content">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Basically I have a section that is not fixed, when choosing the language that section disappears, and then comes the home of the site, basically would be to put that phrase in the home, for 2 seconds when opening it

Comment: @kams123456 If you're doing a page redirect, none of the javascript from the previous page will continue to run after the new page loads. There are some clever things you could do, but it's probably multiple questions in one. Basically you'll have to decide on the load of the javascript of the home page whether a message needs to be displayed or not.